# Regular Expression only allow alphanumeric plus other specific characters

Tags: php, regex

With a PHP function I'm trying to create a RegEx string for preg_replace that will only allow alphanumeric characters plus `! @ # $ % & . ,`

The PHP function is

```
 function clean($var) {
    $regEx="REGEXSTRING";   
    $var = preg_replace($regEx, "", $var);
    return str_replace(array("&", "'"),
    array("&amp;", "&apos;"), $var);
}
```

What would the string be to match what I'm looking for.

:: EDIT :: As I was typing this I figured out what would work for me. Not sure if it is the best solution but it works. But I figured I'd post it here as a solution for other beginners.

The string I used is...

```
$regEx="/[^a-zA-Z0-9 !@#$%&.,]/";
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: As you have solved your question, it might be a good idea to pop the complete solution into an answer and in two days accept is so that this question is considered complete. It will save folks clicking into it to see if they can answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 function clean($var) {
    $regEx="/[^a-zA-Z0-9 !@#$%&.,]/"; 
    $var = preg_replace($regEx, "", $var);
    return str_replace(array("&", "'"),
    array("&amp;", "&apos;"), $var);
}
```